# Merge records if one field matches, but not if another field has values in both records MongoDb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have some records like :

```json
{
id: 1,
phone: "+15555555555",
name: "Acme CO.",
vendorcode: "ACMEC"
},
{
id: 2,
phone: "+15555555555",
name: "Acme corporation company",
vendorcode: "ACMECOMPANY"
},
{
id: 3,
phone: "+15555555555",
name: "Acme Incorporated",
vendorcode: null
}
```

I want to merge records:

IF `phone` field matches, merge the records. (can overwrite values with the values of the next record being merged).

But if there are `vendorcode` non-null values in multiple records, create an arrray of values. So "vendorcode" in the new record would be an array.

I would like the output of the above collection to be something like:

```json
{
phone: "+15555555555",
name: "Acme Co.",
vendorcode: ["ACMEC","ACMECOMPANY"]
}
```

in a new collection.

How to write an aggregation for this in mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by `phone`, select first `name`, `phone`
- `$ifNull` will return `vendorcode` if its not null
- `$addToSet` to make array of unique `vendorcode`
- `$project` to remove `_id` field
- `$out` to write query result in new collection, this will create a new collection and write this query result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$phone",
      phone: { $first: "$phone" },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      vendorcode: {
        $addToSet: { $ifNull: ["$vendorcode", "$$REMOVE"] }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } },
  { $out: "newCollectionName" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Q3GYPsoEqL)

Comment: thanks, that's the first time I've seen $$REMOVE